# Message queue - Dynamic message size - C

Tags: c, dynamic, ipc, message-queue

I'm using static message size for a IPC message queue:

```
/* header */
typedef struct{  
    long type;  
    char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
}msg;

/* main */
msg m;
msgrcv(queueid, &m, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 0);
```

but I need to use dynamic size of data. Something like

```
// header
typedef struct{  
    long type;  
    char *data;
}msg;

// main
msg m;
m.data = (char*) malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );
msgrcv(queueid, &m, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 0);
```

But when I use that it doesn't read anything from the queue and the process is blocked.

Thanks for your time, and apologize for my poor english...

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary length messages are passed through `msgsnd()` and `msgrcv()` like this:

```
typedef struct{  
    long type;  
    char data[1];
}msg;

msg * m = malloc(sizeof(msg) - 1 + NeededSize);
msgrcv(queueid, m, NeededSize, 0, 0);

... // treat m as if the data array was NeededSize elements long
free(m);
```

This allows you to vary what NeededSize is for individual messages.

Comment: @Mat: Pretty common, in particular in windows APIs. Makes sense for these message queues as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was searching